# Difference between dereferencing pointer and accessing array elements

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

I remember an example where the difference between pointers and arrays was demonstrated.

An array decays to a  pointer to the first element in an array when passed as a function parameter, but they are not equivalent, as demonstrated next:

```c
//file file1.c

int a[2] = {800, 801};
int b[2] = {100, 101};
```

```c
//file file2.c

extern int a[2];

// here b is declared as pointer,
// although the external unit defines it as an array
extern int *b; 

int main() {

  int x1, x2;

  x1 = a[1]; // ok
  x2 = b[1]; // crash at runtime

  return 0;
}
```

The linker does not type-check for external variables so no errors are generated at compile time. The problem is that `b` is in fact an array, but the compilation unit `file2` is unaware of that and treats `b` as a pointer, resulting in a crash when trying to dereference it.

I remember when this was explained it made perfect sense, but now I can't remember the explanation nor I can come up to it on my own.

So I guess the question is how is an array treated differently than a pointer when accessing elements? (because I thought that `p[1]` is converted to (the assembly equivalent of) `*(p + 1)` regardless if `p` is an array or a pointer — I am obviously wrong).

---

The assembly generated by the two dereferences (VS 2013):
*note:* `1158000h` and `1158008h` are the memory addresses of `a` and `b` respectively

```
    12:   x1 = a[1];
0115139E  mov         eax,4  
011513A3  shl         eax,0  
011513A6  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+1158000h]  
011513AC  mov         dword ptr [x1],ecx  
    13:   x2 = b[1];
011513AF  mov         eax,4  
011513B4  shl         eax,0  
011513B7  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[1158008h]  
011513BD  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax]  
011513C0  mov         dword ptr [x2],edx
```

Comment: I could explain all the details, but I could not do it better than this. check page 96 http://books.google.com.au/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Deep+C+secrets&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-j4KU9L5Ec3jkgWblYHoAg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=extern%20&f=false

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by @tesseract in the comments: [Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Deep%20C%20secrets&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-j4KU9L5Ec3jkgWblYHoAg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=extern%20&f=false) (page 96), I came up with a simple answer (a simple dumb down version of the explanation in the book; for a full academic answer read the book):

- when declared `int a[2]`:

  - the compiler has for `a` an address where this variable is stored. This address is also the address of the array since the type of the variable is array.
  - Accessing `a[1]` means:

    - retrieving that address,
    - adding the offset and
    - accessing the memory at this computed new address.
- when declared `int *b`:

  - the compiler also has an address for `b` but this is the address of the pointer variable, not the array.
  - So accessing `b[1]` means:

    - retrieving that address,
    - accessing that location to get the value of `b`, i.e. the address of the array
    - adding an offset to this address and then
    - accessing the final memory location.

Answer (score 12):

```
// in file2.c

extern int *b; // b is declared as a pointer to an integer

// in file1.c

int b[2] = {100, 101}; // b is defined and initialized as an array of 2 ints
```

The linker links them both to same memory address, however since the symbol `b` has different types in `file1.c` and `file2.c`, the same memory location is interpreted differently.

```
// in file2.c

int x2;  // assuming sizeof(int) == 4
x2 = b[1]; // b[1] == *(b+1) == *(100 + 1) == *(104) --> segfault
```

`b[1]` is evaluated first as `*(b+1)`. This means get the value at the memory location `b` is bound to, add `1` to it (pointer arithmetic) to get a new address, load that value into the CPU register, store that value at the location `x2` is bound to. So, the value at the location `b` is bound to is `100`, add `1` to it to get `104` (pointer arithmetic; `sizeof *b` is 4) and get the value at the address `104`! This is wrong and undefined behaviour and most likely will cause program crash.

There is a difference in how the elements of an array are accessed and how the values pointed to by a pointer are accessed. Let's take an example.

```
int a[] = {100, 800};
int *b = a;
```

`a` is an array of `2` integers and `b` is a pointer to an integer initialized to the address of the first element of `a`. Now when `a[1]` is accessed, it means get whatever is there at offset `1` from the address of `a[0]`, the address (and the next block) to which the symbol `a` is bound. That's one assembly instruction. It's as if some information is embedded into the array symbol so that the CPU can fetch an element at an offset from the base address of the array in one instruction. When you access `*b` or `b[0]` or `b[1]`, you first get the content of `b` which is an address, then do the pointer arithmetic to get a new address and then get whatever is there at that address. So the CPU has to first load the content of `b`, evaluate `b+1` (for `b[1]`) and then load the content at address `b+1`. That's two assembly instructions.

For an extern array, you don't need to specify its size.The only requirement is that it must match with its external definition. Therefore both the following statements are equivalent:

```
extern int a[2];  // equivalent to the below statement
extern int a[];
```

You must match the type of the variable in its declaration with its external definition. The linker doesn't check for types of variables when resolving references of symbols. Only functions have the types of the function encoded into the function name. Therefore you won't get any warning or error and it would compile just fine.

Technically, the linker or some compiler component could track what type the symbol represents, and then give an error or warning. But there is no requirement from the standard to do so. You are required to do the right thing.

Comment: Why does this happen when you declare extern, but not if you declare on the same file? For example, why does "int a[2] = {100,200}; int *b = a; printf("b[1] = %d\n",b[1]);" work correctly?

Comment: @Cantfindname that's because `a` and `b` are two different variables. They are bound to different memory addresses. However, `extern` variables all *link* to the same memory location. They are like aliases for the same memory location in two different file scope.

Comment: Please be a bit more careful with differentiating compatible and equivalent definitions.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't fully answer your question, but it gives you a hint to what is going on. Modify your code a little bit to give

```
//file1.c

int a[2] = {800, 801};
int b[2] = {255, 255};

#include <stdio.h>

extern int a[2];

// here b is declared as pointer,
// although the external unit declares it as an array

extern int *b; 
int *c;

int main() {

  int x1, x2;

  x1 = a[1]; // ok
  c = b;
  printf("allocated x1 OK\n");
  printf("a is %p\n", a);
  printf("c is %p\n", c);
  x2 = *(c+1);
  printf("%d %d\n", x1, x2);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, when you run it, you still get a segfault. But just before you do, you get an insight into why:

```
allocated x1 OK
a is 0x10afa4018
c is 0xff000000ff
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The value of pointer c is not what you expect: instead of being the pointer to the start of array `b` (which would be a sensible memory location close to `a`), it seems to contain the *contents* of array *b*... (`0xff` is `255` in hex, of course).

I can't explain very clearly why that is - for that, see the [link](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Deep+C+secrets&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-j4KU9L5Ec3jkgWblYHoAg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=extern%20&f=false) that was given by @tesseract in the comments (really all of chapter 4 is extremely useful).