# Why does returning local array pointers work whenever I first iterate through the array?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, local-variables

I played around with returning array pointers to gain greater understanding of how they work and found something I cannot explain.

Why does the following code work whenever I iterate through the return array before actually returning it (see the conditional section)?
Is it because C is lazy and does not actually write the array in memory as it thinks that it'll never get accessed anyways?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//returns pointer to array terminated by (-1)
int* thisDoesntMakeAnySense(int randomNumber)  {
    int array[randomNumber + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < randomNumber; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    array[randomNumber] = -1;

#ifdef ENABLE_CLUDGE
    int i = 0;
    while(array[i] != -1) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        i++;
    }
#endif
    return array;
}

int main() {
    int* test = thisDoesntMakeAnySense(3);

    while(*test != -1) {
        printf("%d\n", *test);
        test++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Is it because C is lazy and does not actually write the array in memory_ No, it's because the array has local scope and his lifetime ends when you exit the function, to make it visible: 1) Use dynamic memory `int *array = malloc((randomNumber + 1) * sizeof *array);` or 2) Make it `static` :  `static int array[randomNumber + 1];`

Comment: "Why does the following code work" -->  What behavior did you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when your compiler sees the array is not read before it is returned, it eliminates the code that writes to the array.

This is not laziness; it is optimization. The compiler has to do **more** work to figure these things out. A goal of doing more work in the compiler is to create a program that does **less** work (or uses less space or other resources) when it executes.

This behavior is not guaranteed by the C standard, but is a common feature of compilers.

Note that the compiler is able to ignore the reads of the array that you attempt in `main` because these reads are not defined by the C standard. In `thisDoesntMakeAnySense`, the array `array` is created as the function begins, and it is (in the model of computing used by the C standard) destroyed when the function returns. Although the function returns a pointer to the array, the array does not exist (in the model), and the pointer is not valid. Because the pointer is not valid, the compiler is not required to give any meaning to the code in `main` that uses the pointer. Therefore, the compiler is permitted by the C standard to reason that this program writes to the array but never reads from it, not even in `main`, and therefore the writes to the array have no effect and may be removed.

In general, a compiler is not required to generate a program that executes your program exactly as its source code is written. The C standard only requires the compiler (or your C implementation generally, including all the standard headers and libraries and supporting software) to generate a program that has the same observable behavior as your source code does. Observable behavior includes:

- Data written to files.
- Input and output interactions.
- Accesses to volatile objects.

Thus, the output of a `printf` statement is observable behavior. But writing into an array that is never used is not observable behavior, so the compiler is not required to generate code for it.

In regard to the code that happens to make your program appears to work, that code reads from the array and writes to output (which is observable behavior). So the program must<sup>1</sup> write that output. Your compiler apparently implements this by actually creating the array, writing to it, then reading the array and writing it to standard output. Then, upon returning to `main`, because the array was created and its data in memory has not yet been altered, the code in `main` to print it happens to “work.” However, the compiler could have implemented the required observable behavior by simply printing the output using a constant string generated at compile time and not using an array at all. In this case, the code in `main` would fail.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The program must write the output if the program is otherwise okay. However, the fact that there is undefined behavior later in the program’s execution poisons the upstream execution. If program control enters a path on which there is, unconditionally, undefined behavior, the behavior of that entire path is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the following code work whenever I iterate through the return array before actually returning it? (uncomment section) Is it because C is lazy and does not actually write the array in memory as it thinks that it'll never get accessed anyways?

If indeed the program works reliably for you as described, then it is because of the particular quirks of your C implementation, as they apply to and interact with the particular code presented.

The C language specifications are clear that when the lifetime of an object ends, any pointers (in)to it become indeterminate.  Attempting to access the object pointed to by an indeterminate pointer value produces undefined behavior.  On any given run, undefined behavior can absolutely turn out to be something that you describe as "it works", but C provides no justification for relying on that.

Answer (score 0):

When you simply create an array in a function, that array is scoped to that function.

In order to circumvent that, you have to use `malloc()`. `malloc()` lets you dynamically allocate memory by telling the operating system "I want this much memory. Give it to me and leave it alone, I'll do the rest".

TLDR:

Use `malloc()` to ensure that the array persists outside the function.

Comment: Well, by some stretch it is. It decays to a pointer. It's accessed through pointer arithmetic. It's a fancy pointer.

Comment: As much as an `int` is a `double`. Actually even less.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi no it's not. It really isn't. And as soon as ppl learning C stop thinking as arrays being  fancy pointers the better.

Comment: A pointer is an object whose value is the address of another object. An array is an object whose value is a contiguous container of other objects. An array **is not** a fancy pointer.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer in my post. An array *variable*, not the underlying memory, is essentially a fancy pointer. If you print it, you'll get an address in memory.

Comment: No! An array is not a pointer!! Let me say this again: an array is not a pointer. An array **appears** to behave like a pointer in certain constructs, but that is just because of the "array decays to a pointer". But an array (variable, object whatever you want to call it) is fundamentally different than a pointer. Thinking of an array like a pointer will eventually come back and bite you: see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972465/difference-between-dereferencing-pointer-and-accessing-array-elements