# What is the difference between char s[] and char *s when it comes to initialisation?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

with string literal declaration like this:

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

and this

```
char *ptr = "hello";
```

initialisation of ptr with str is possible:

```
ptr = str;     //valid
```

but not viceversa:

```
str = ptr;    //invalid
```

although str being a char array would hold the address of the first element anyways, then what makes the second case invalid and not the first one?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972465/difference-between-dereferencing-pointer-and-accessing-array-elements) stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
char str[] = "hello";
char *ptr = str; /* valid */
```

above pointer assignment `char *ptr = str;` is valid as `ptr` is pointer and its assigned with `str` which points to base address of `str`, and in this case *`ptr` is not a constant pointer* i.e it can point to different memory location, hence it can be assigned like `ptr = str`.

But in below case

```
char *ptr = "hello";
char str[10] = ptr; /* invalid */
```

the statement `char str[10] = ptr;` is not valid as `str` *name itself represents one address* and by doing `char str[10] = ptr;` you are trying to modify the base address of `str` which is not possible because *array is not a pointer*.

Comment: A feature that I really wish C would include is to create a modifiable char pointer that points to a modifiable string like in the first example, but in one line.

Answer (score 1):

At very first, the string `"hello"` actually is an array located somewhere in (immutable!) memory.

You can assign it to a pointer, which is what you do in second example (`char* ptr = ...`). In this case, the pointer just points to that immutable array, i. e. holds the array's address. Recommendation at this point: Although legal in C (unlike C++), don't assign string literals to `char*` pointers, assign them only to `char const*` pointers; this reflects immutability much better.

In the second example, you use the first array (the literal) to initialise *another* array (`str`). This other array `str` (if not provided explicit length, as in the example) will use the first array's length and *copy* the contents of. This second array isn't immutable any more and you can modify it (as long as you do not exceed its bounds).

Assignment: Arrays decay to pointers automatically, if the context they are used in requires a pointer. This is why your first assignment example works, you assign a pointer (the one the array decayed to) to another one (`ptr`). Actually, exactly the same as in your second initialisation example, you don't do anything different there either...

But arrays aren't pointers, and pointers never decay backwards to arrays. This is why the second assignment example doesn't work.